# Show Posts Based on Viewer Timezone in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I'm working on a site that is scheduled to show tutorials contents to a student at a specific time. I'm using Laravel Framework and Carbon package. I have two fields in the Lessons table. The date/time field and the debut_timezone field to show tutorials to a student based on the scheduled date and time. It's working fine cause I'm using the WHERE clause in Laravel Eloquent.

```
// For example: 
$student_id = \Auth::user()->id;
$lessons = Lesson::where('student_id', $student_id)->where('debut_date', Carbon::now())->get();
```

How can I use the timezone field so that it will only show tutorial to students based on their timezone. For example, Students on the East Coast can view their lessons 3 hours before students on the West Coast and so on. In this case, when we go global, students in Asia will be able to view their lesson hours before students in the U.S, and so forth.

Please help, please?

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch the student's timezone based on their IP address (location - country) or their stored timezone in db if you have the option. Once you have the timezone of the student you can change your query to this.

```
$student_id = auth()->id();
$student_tz = ''; // timezone based on ip or other condition.
$lessons = Lesson::where('student_id', $student_id)
    ->whereDate('debut_date', Carbon::now($student_tz))
    ->get();
```

You should also use `whereDate` instead of `where` since an exact comparison isn't exactly what you need.

Comment: Hi @Sandeesh, thanks for your quick respond. Unfortunately, we don't have a field included for students to select their timezone. However, we do  store students' IP addresses. Does Carbon has a function to determine timezone based on IP address?

Comment: @PrinceJ it's not so easy to get timezone from IP. You need to use a third party service through api or a package to handle this. You can search around and figure out the best option based on your requirements. There are many free and paid services to help you out.